# Programmatically Compile Flash (.fla) files

Tags: flash

Is there a while to compile flash files (.fla) into swfs? want to use ruby, php or another language to compile fla files.

Answer (score 0):

Seee the [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) language - Its compiler can compile Haxe (very simmilar to Actionscript) to `swfs`. It is written in Ocaml I think (but I could be wrong).
You can see its implemmentation and learn abut the Flash VM opcodes to use them in your parsers (in ruby, python etc).

Maybe there is a better way thought.